# Is (a^b)/(b^a) greater than 1 for b > a?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it correct to say that:

$(a ^ b)/(b^a) > 1$, for all values of a and b given that $b > a$?

Can this be easily proven and if so, how?

Comment: Not in all cases.

Comment: What is the value of $\frac{2^3}{3^2}?$

Comment: Try to think of a counter-example.

Comment: It's true if $a\ge e$.

Comment: Ahh, I thought I was missing something, thank you. How can you prove this for $a \ge e$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not correct.  Assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a ^ b/b^a > 1 &\Leftrightarrow & (a^b/b^a)^{1/ab} > 1\\
 &\Leftrightarrow & a^{1/a}/b^{1/b} >1\\
&\Leftrightarrow& a^{1/a}>b^{1/b}\\
&\Leftrightarrow& f(a)>f(b),
\end{eqnarray*}
where $f(x)=x^{1/x}=\exp(x^{-1} \log x)$.  $f$  has derivative 
$(1-\log x) x^{-2} \exp(x^{-1}\log x)$.  This is positive for $x<e$ and negative for $x>e$, so $f(x)$ increases up to its maximum at $x=e$ and decreases afterwards.  To have $f(a)>f(b)$ whenever $a<b$, $f(x)$ would have to be steadily decreasing, but it isn't.

If $a$ and $b$ both exceed $e$, as pointed out in the comments we do have
\begin{eqnarray*}
a ^ b/b^a > 1 &\Leftrightarrow & f(a)>f(b)\\
 &\Leftrightarrow & a<b.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

A few counterexamples:

- $a=1,b>1 \implies a^b<b^a$
- $a=2,b=3 \implies a^b<b^a$
- $a=2,b=4 \implies a^b=b^a$